# Image Scrapping with the help of Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am attempting to extract an image link using Selenium, and the following code is my current implementation.

```py
def fetch_image_urls(query:str, max_links_to_fetch:int, wd:webdriver=driver, sleep_between_interactions:int=3):
    def scroll_to_end(wd):
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        sleep(sleep_between_interactions)        
    try:
        search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&q={q}&oq={q}&gs_l=img"
        # load the page
        print(search_url)
        print(search_url.format(q=query))
        wd = webdriver.Chrome()
        wd.get(search_url.format(q=query))
        image_urls = set()
        image_count = 0
        results_start = 0
        # actual_images1 = wd.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'img.n3VNCb')
        # print(actual_images1)
        while image_count < max_links_to_fetch:
            scroll_to_end(wd)
            thumbnail_results = wd.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"img.Q4LuWd")
            number_results = len(thumbnail_results)
            print(f"Found: {number_results} search results. Extracting links from {results_start}:{number_results}")
            for img in thumbnail_results[results_start:number_results]:
                
                try:
                    img.click()
                    sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
                except Exception:
                    continue
                actual_images = wd.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'img.n3VNCb') --------> error line 
                
                print("actual_images:",actual_images)
                for actual_image in actual_images:
                    if actual_image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in actual_image.get_attribute('src'):
                        image_urls.add(actual_image.get_attribute('src'))
                image_count = len(image_urls)
                if len(image_urls) >= max_links_to_fetch:
                    print(f"Found: {len(image_urls)} image links, done!")
                    break
                break
            else:
                print("Found:", len(image_urls), "image links, looking for more ...")
                sleep(30)
                return
                load_more_button = wd.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd")
                if load_more_button:
                    wd.execute_script("document.querySelector('.mye4qd').click();")
                
            
            results_start = len(thumbnail_results)
    except:
        pass

    return image_urls
```

Initially, the code was functioning properly and successfully retrieving the image link. However, after a few days, it is now only able to retrieve the thumbnail link to fecth proper image link